# schema.org product tag incomplete cannot find what I'm missing

Tags: schema.org, microformats, rich-snippets

I am getting "Warning: Incomplete microdata with schema.org." When validating my page with the Google Structured Data Testing Tool.

I have these properties defined:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-176-34-78-212.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com%2Fdev-avc%2Folimp-whey-protein-complex-100.html&html=

Any ideas what I am missing? I looked and I don't see anything I am missing.

I copy / paste an old post, just changing the link for the google structured data.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try, putting a PRICE tag inside the schema.org/Product, and more information in the offers, like NAME, DESCRIPTION.

Also i saw that availability is part of another itemscope, http://schema.org/ItemAvailability

Comment: Finally we discard the whole site and we are currently working in a new one, so we gonna start from zero and try also with your suggestions. 
Many thanks for your answer and sorry for didn't tell you before, forgot to check this back ! :-)